# Merging predicted values into measured values

Tags: performance, r

I created the following function below to merge the real values with the predicted values (when real are absent) in a new column in `data.frame`. The function actually works, but I would like to optimize it, because with the dataset that I work with, the function takes about two hours to run.

The function seems to be slowed down by the loop.

```
p <-            
  function(object, newdata = NULL, type = c("link", "response", "terms"), 
           rse.fit = FALSE, dispersion = NULL, terms = NULL,
           na.action = na.pass, ...)
  { 
{
    pred <- predict (object,newdata)    

      }

    vetor1 <- (newdata$ALT)         # Creates a column vector from the actual heights of the data.frame
    vetor1[is.na(vetor1)] <- 0      # Replaces the NA's present in the vector created above the numeric value 0
    vetor2 <- c(pred)           # Creates a vector from the predicted data
    for(i in 1:length(vetor1)){     # The loop is executed until all values vector1 pass the following condition
      if(vetor1[i]==0.00){      # If a value of the first vector has the value 0, ie, if it is absent
        vetor1[i]=vetor2[i]     # Then the predicted value will replace the missing value
        newdata$ALTMISTA <- vetor1  # The vector1, already possessing the actual values and the predicted values merged into the same vector goes                   on to become a new column in data.frame, this column is called a ALTMISTA
      }
    }
    return (newdata)            
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that the call to `predict` is not what is taking most of the time, so I'm not including that in my analysis.

One thing that is slowing down your code is that you are assigning `vetor1` to `newdata$ALTMISTA` every iteration of the loop (well, every iteration that is 0). That could be pulled out of the loop since it only needs to be done once.

```
vetor1 <- (newdata$ALT)         # Creates a column vector from the actual heights of the data.frame
vetor1[is.na(vetor1)] <- 0      # Replaces the NA's present in the vector created above the numeric value 0
vetor2 <- c(pred)           # Creates a vector from the predicted data
for(i in 1:length(vetor1)){     # The loop is executed until all values vector1 pass the following condition
    if(vetor1[i]==0.00){      # If a value of the first vector has the value 0, ie, if it is absent
        vetor1[i]=vetor2[i]     # Then the predicted value will replace the missing value
    }
}
newdata$ALTMISTA <- vetor1  # The vector1, already possessing the actual values and the predicted values merged into the same vector goes                   on to become a new column in data.frame, this column is called a ALTMISTA
return (newdata)
```

Second, you replace `NA` with `0`, and then test against `0`. That means you are replacing both `NA`'s and any `0`'s in the data. If you only want to replace `NA`'s, just replace those without recoding them.

```
vetor1 <- (newdata$ALT)         # Creates a column vector from the actual heights of the data.frame
vetor2 <- c(pred)           # Creates a vector from the predicted data
for(i in 1:length(vetor1)){     # The loop is executed until all values vector1 pass the following condition
    if(is.na(vetor1[i])){      # If a value of the first vector is NA, ie, if it is absent
        vetor1[i]=vetor2[i]     # Then the predicted value will replace the missing value
    }
}
newdata$ALTMISTA <- vetor1  # The vector1, already possessing the actual values and the predicted values merged into the same vector goes                   on to become a new column in data.frame, this column is called a ALTMISTA
return (newdata)
```

Now the explicit loop can be replaced by vectorized functions, in this case `ifelse`

```
vetor1 <- (newdata$ALT)         # Creates a column vector from the actual heights of the data.frame
vetor2 <- c(pred)           # Creates a vector from the predicted data
vetor1 <- ifelse(is.na(vetor1), vetor2, vetor1) # replace elements of vetor1 that are NA with corresponding elements of vetor2
newdata$ALTMISTA <- vetor1  # The vector1, already possessing the actual values and the predicted values merged into the same vector goes                   on to become a new column in data.frame, this column is called a ALTMISTA
return (newdata)
```

Finally you can eliminate some single use intermediate variables. This may not appreciably speed up the function, but it does make for cleaner code.

```
vetor1 <- (newdata$ALT)
newdata$ALTMISTA <- ifelse(is.na(vetor1), pred, vetor1)
return (newdata)
```

As you did not provide example data, I was not able to benchmark these alternatives (nor, for that matter, even run them).

Comment: Thanks! Running only with the first suggested change, reduced from 3 hours to 15 seconds (which I found rather odd for the size of the data set, but it's all right). =D